# Plot time series data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, time-series

I have to plot a time series data in MATLAB. The Y axis is a parameter taken six hourly for each day in a certain month of the year. And 44 such years have been taken into account. From 1958 to 2001. So the points on the X axis are 4*31*44=5456. How can I plot the data efficiently in MATLAB? The data file has two column vectors. 
I have to plot the x axis so that it shows 44 July s from 1958 to 2001 . Each July has 124 points.
One for the time points (5456 points) so 5456 rows and other for the parameter measured. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you want, and even more unclear when reading your response to the current answer. Do you want to average the data for each month, or otherwise reduce the number of datapoints somehow? Label the axis with year info? What does "efficiently" mean to you?

Comment: I want to keep the number of data points same. But to label the x axis by 44 Julys.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't give any more details, it is hard to know exactly what you are asking. If you have a matrix `A` with two columns, then you are looking for

```
plot( A(:,1), A(:,2) )
```

Alternatively, perhaps you want to see the histogram, `hist`, or the scatter plot `scatter`.

Comment: Well, my data has the time points in one column and parameter in the other column. But if I try to simply plot it in MATLAB, the figure plots the parameter against 5456 time points. Which I dont want.

Comment: It is still not clear what the issue is. Perhaps you want to use `scatter`? Please show your plot, and explain why it is not what you want.

Comment: Here is the plot https://www.dropbox.com/s/wovdiyq4ggc7c0b/swh.fig?dl=0  The plot has 5456 time points in the x axis which I do not want.

Comment: Please save that as a png or jpg and copy into your question. I do not have Matlab on this machine.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the histogram? An example of what you want the plot to look like would be great... If you don't want the x-axis, then what do you want?

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible anyhow to format the x axis to represent the time scale I want? Like the data is for 44 years from 1958 to 2001. Taken 4 times a day for each day in the month of July.

Comment: You probably want `datetick`:  https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I have to plot 44 July s in the x axis and each July has 124 data points.

Comment: Please add your requirements to the question and somebody else can help

Answer (score 0):

Well your X-axis(time data) is most probably not in **datetime** format & hence the problem.Once that is done, the plot will show what you want. You should try and change it to **datetime** & then try

```
plot(X,Y)
```

or

```
plot(A(:,1),A(:,2))
```

whichever be your data format